# SetConsoleMode() and ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING?

Tags: c++, c, windows, console

According to MSDN, the `dwMode` parameter for the `SetConsoleMode()` function should allow `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` (0x04).

My Visual Studio (2013 Ultimate with Update 5) does not define that constant. It only has these two:

```
#define ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT    0x0001
#define ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT  0x0002
```

Was `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` removed?

I am trying to use it like this, so that I can control the cursor using the VT100 escape sequences.

```
HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
DWORD dwMode = 0;
GetConsoleMode(hOut, &dwMode);
dwMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
SetConsoleMode(hOut, dwMode);
```

For reference, see this MSDN [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686033(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: It was added in the Win10 SDK.  Your SDK is older, 8.1 probably.  I'd assume you'll also need Win10 to use it.  Not sure, you'd have to try.

Comment: It is defined in VS 2017. Thanks for the code sample!

Answer (score 6):

If your SDK is too old, `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` may not be defined.

You can manually define it with the following code:

```
#ifndef ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING
#define ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING 0x0004
#endif
```

Comment: I tried that, and it builds, but the console doesn't respond as desired.

Comment: I think the problem is that it needs a newer command window .. apparently it is now build into the Windows 10 command window and not the older ones.

Comment: Yes: it requires Windows 10 with a build number 10586 or greater.

Comment: and to add more confusion they write minimum supported client as 2000.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal - The **API's** minimum supported client is Windows 2000. Specific settings may only be supported by later OS releases.