# RichTextBox unrecognized characters

Tags: c#, character-encoding, richtextbox

I have created a simple MUD client that has finally managed to connect to the server. However, I'm getting a bunch of unrecognizable characters in my output window.

[image: Screenshot]

I have highlighted some of the characters on this screenshot.
I believe most of these are colorcodes, some are hyperlinks. Some might even be newline characters.

I think that the charset on the server is ASCII (it can be changed by the user.)
Here is the code that presents the text in my client:

```
    private void getDataFromServer() {
        byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
        updateOutputWindow(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead));
    }

    private void updateOutputWindow(string text) {
        if (InvokeRequired) {
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () {
                updateOutputWindow(text);
            }));
        }
        else {
            rtb_outputWindow.AppendText(text);
            MessageBox.Show(text);
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to somehow interpret these characters?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: I tried doing: updateOutputWindow(Encoding.Default.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead));

And going through all the different Encodings.
The ones who worked were all pretty similar, but the unrecognized characters remained.

I read somewhere that my client doesn't have MXP support - I don't know how to get it, though..

Comment: Have you read the link I posted? it is not about encoding. It is about emulating VT100 terminals

Comment: I see. Is there a way to easily convert these escape chars into something else (color, for example)?

According to the link you posted the first character is 'ESC' (it shows up as a "whitebox" in my client) - is there some way to make it show up as a proper character?

I tried doing this just to see what would happen:
if (text.Contains("[1;37m")) MessageBox.Show("escape char found!");
the MessageBox showed up as expected.

Comment: 1- Change your project settings to console (project/settings/application/output type) this will open a console window. 2- enable "ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING" like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574274/setconsolemode-fails-with-zero-lasterror-0) 3-Write your data to console