# Trouble enable virtual terminal processing for windows in c

Tags: c, windows

I'm trying to enable VTP following these [instructions/examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#samples).

But I keep getting the following error:

> error: 'ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING' undeclared (first use in this function)

I'm still super new to coding and I feel like I'm just missing something stupid.

Answer (score 1):

As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772468/setconsolemode-and-enable-virtual-terminal-processing), this is because only newer versions of the SDK have this defined. You can define it yourself using `#define` as suggested in the answer(s).